# What is the "USB Controls" device listed in “Settings ˘ Bluetooth & other devices?”

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

On my Dell Precision 7720 laptop running Microsoft Windows 10, version 20H2, OS Vuild 19042.928, I just discovered a device named "USB Controls" listed under “Settings > Bluetooth & other devices > Audio.” It is also listed under “Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Devices.” I have two questions about it:

1. What kind of device is this? A link to relevant (Microsoft) documentation would be appreciated.
2. Since which Windows version is this appearing under Settings | Bluetooth and other devices?

Some background to this question: I didn't notice this device before, but now it's definitely there. And on my computer, it is reporting a malfunction. Since the only option I had for the device is to remove it, and I was not sure what the device represented, I started investigating.

The device seems to be some kind of virtual device enumerating all kinds of control features of other, actual devices. As far as I can tell, it is not clearly associated with one single device in the Windows Device Manager.

In “Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Devices,” all other devices are listed with a single or maximum two categories, but "USB Controls" is listed with 4 device categories:

> Video and Imaging Devices; Audio Devices; External Adapters and Hardware Components; Keyboards, Mice and Other Input Devices

Also in “Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Devices,” I can select the device, right click it with the mouse and select "Properties" to show the associated USB Controls Properties dialog window. On the Hardware tab of that window, many actual hardware devices are listed.

One of the devices listed there was the ambient light sensor of my external display, which is attached via a Thunderbolt connection. Since I don't have the correct driver for this sensor, the device reported an error. After replacing the failed incorrect device driver for the device with a null device driver, the error reported on the USB Control device in “Settings > Bluetooth & other devices > Audio” went away too!

I also searched the registry for a key, value or data matching the whole string “USB Controls.” There were no search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the "USB Controls" audio device corresponds to the Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller, which is a component inside of my LG UltraFine 5K external monitor.

Whenever I detach the monitor by disconnecting the USB-C cable from the monitor or from my Intel Thunderbolt 3 port, the USB Controls disappear. And when I reconnect the cable, the USB Controls entry shows up again.

The Fresco Logic USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller is listed in the Windows Device Manager under the "Universal Serial Bus controllers" node. When I disable it, the USB Controls disappear and when I re-enable it, the USB Controls re-appear.

Finally, while there are many hardware devices listed in “Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Devices,” on the hardware tab of the USB Controls device properties dialog window, these are all device sub-nodes present under the Fresno Logic FL1000 controller node.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what the "USB Controls" device is though. I'm still left wondering what it can be used for/what can be controlled.

Comment: It is the Fresco Logic FL1100 USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller, a USB host controller (see [What is a USB Host Controller](https://www.easytechjunkie.com/what-is-a-usb-host-controller.htm)) manufactured by Fresco Logic.